# How to use a JOIN inside a CASE expression?

Tags: postgresql, case, exists

I have four tables like this:

**company**:

| id | companyContactID | customerID | companyTeamID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 21 | 54 |
| 2 | 14 | 12 | 78 |

**document_associated_company**:

| id | companyID | documentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 98 |
| 2 | 1 | 12 |

**document**

| id | documentTypeID |
| --- | --- |
| 98 | 67 |
| 12 | 87 |

**document_type**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 67 | NDA |
| 87 | SOW |

And I have an SQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT CASE
  WHEN company."customerID" IS NOT NULL THEN 'customer'
  WHEN company."companyContactID" IS NOT NULL THEN 'lead'
  WHEN company."companyTeamID" IS NOT NULL THEN 'lead'
  ELSE 'company'
  END AS status
FROM   company;
```

I have used a `CASE` expression here to create a new column named `status`. Basically, according to the several conditions I set the status of the `company`. Additionally, I need to check whether the company has a document attached with a certain type. For example, if the `company` have a `document` with the type NDA attached, then its status would be 'active'. For this I would have to put several `JOIN` statements. Any idea how to integrate this into the `CASE` expression?

**Expected result:**

| status |
| --- |
| active |
| customer |

Comment: Where `'active'` is taken from? The status for both rows in `company` is `'customer'` and not `'company'`, so additional rule shouldn't be applied. PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6c5f6fcfa489d5e734dc0e7c5abd916c

Comment: @ErgestBasha No it's not. For both those conditions, "lead" should be the result. I should be refactoring it by adding and `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw in an [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) expression:

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT  -- select list can be empty
                     FROM    document_associated_company a
                     JOIN    document                    d ON d.id = a."documentID"
                     JOIN    document_type               t ON t.id = d."documentTypeID"
                     WHERE   a."comanyID" = c.id
                     AND     t.name = 'NDA') THEN 'active'
        WHEN c."customerID"       IS NOT NULL THEN 'customer'
        WHEN c."companyContactID" IS NOT NULL THEN 'lead'
        WHEN c."companyTeamID"    IS NOT NULL THEN 'lead'
        ELSE 'company'
       END AS status
FROM   company c;
```

(Making a couple of assumptions about your relational design.)